# iPhone 6 / iPhone 6+ launch screen size issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, launch-screen

I want to optimize my app for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+

But I have a launch screen size problem.

I created a simple project, and AppDelegate's code is:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewControllerOne.h" //xib screen size is 4 inch.
#import "ViewControllerTwo.h" // xib screen size is 4.7 inch.
#import "ViewControllerThree.h" // xib screen size is 5.5 inch.


@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {


        if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0) {//4 inch

            ViewControllerOne *first = [[ViewControllerOne alloc]init];
            UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:first];
            self.window.rootViewController = navigation;


        }

        else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667.0){//4.7inch

            ViewControllerTwo * second = [[ViewControllerTwo alloc]init];
            UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:second];
            self.window.rootViewController = navigation;

        }


        else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736.0){//5.5inch

            ViewControllerThree *third = [[ViewControllerThree alloc]init];
            UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:third];
            self.window.rootViewController = navigation;

        }


    }


    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES;
}

@end
```

When I run iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+ simulator, it always appears 4inch screen when I run this project.(I included three launch image(Default-667h@2x.png, Default-736@3x.png, Default-568@2x.png) also.

What I have to do to resolve this problem.

I checked others question that similar to mine, and used their code, but all of those not works. That is maybe my technical skills relatively row.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Comment: have you declared your launch images in the project's plist? or the projects "General" tab when you click on the project file?

Comment: Thank you Bob and Smith! I just solved this problem. I did not declared my launch images in info.plist. I declared launch images and all is well!

Comment: why don't you use auto-layout? you should not create an individual view controller for each possible screen size (btw, where is the view controller for 3.5" device in that case?)... but which is more important: how would you maintain your project efficiently in the future? or spending 4x more time is the desired way? I'm just asking innocently, because it seems that it has not been engineered too professionally...

Comment: Thank you for your answer holex. I think you are right.I have to think more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Once you specify the images in Assets Catalog you will see the right images

Go to **YourAppTarget> General> App Icons and Launch Images> Launch Image Source > Use asset Catalog**

and then drag the appropriate size for each device.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding images you can also add a **Launch Screen File**. This is a .XIB file that allows you to specify constraints in addition of launch images. It only works on **iOS8**. To support iPhone 6 and 6+, we only add this file and specify constraints:

To set the Launch Screen File add it to your project:

**File > New > User Interface > Launch Screen**

Then go to: **YourAppTarget > General > App Icons and Launch Image s> Launch Screen File > Set your newly created image**

*You will still need launch images for Retina 4" and 3.5", if you are supporting iOS 7.*

Comment: Thank you Legoless, It's very helpful.